# How do I call the children of a different parent in Radiant CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, tags, radiant

In my nav, I have "Services". Since there are many services, I have a subnav that drops down. I would like to make this nav dynamic and have it call the page titles for any of the children of "Services". But there doesn't seem to be any tags that can call other parents besides their self. Since its the main nav, the children are every page from the root of the site.

Has anyone made a tag that can do this or know where I can find one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the children tag in a find tag then the children should return the children of the page that was found rather than the current page.

```
<r:find url="/services">
  <r:children:each>
    <r:link />
  </r:children:each>
</r:find>
```

Comment: Sweet! I knew it had to be in there. Thanks so much.